# attach drive in virtual box for best performance

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running virtual box 3.02 on a windows xp host.

Is there any benefit to using emulated SCSI as opposed to the emulated ide for attaching drives. The documentation states:

*Like a real SATA controller, VirtualBox’s virtual SATA controller operates faster
and also consumes less CPU resources than the virtual IDE controller.*

I know in other platforms Emulated SCSI is faster as well. Does anyone know if that holds true in virtual box?

Which method typically yields the best performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see ... the documentation says it's faster, you know it's faster on other platforms, and yet you're asking this question?

Comment: Perhaps my question wasn't framed very clearly. Do you get the same performance advantages from SCSI as SATA or is the performance in between SATA and IDE? I was wondering if it was an omission in the documentation. I don't think I can switch to SATA with AHCI mode after installing the guest and the docs recommend seem to discourage using it.

Comment: Your question wasn't framed clearly at all. I'd definitely edit it if you can.